# Can you get rid of file extensions for bash commands in cygwin?

Tags: bash, cygwin, tab-completion

I've just started messing around with cygwin. I've noticed when use the tab auto-complete feature for commands it always adds a '.exe' even though one isn't needed to run the command.

Is there a way to hide the '.exe' part of the bash commands?

Answer (score 2):

The tab auto-complete feature simply prints the name of the file.

If the file is named `grep.exe`, then that is what will print.

Possibly a better option than tab auto-complete would be Control-R

```
$ grep -r Steven *

(reverse-i-search)`S': grep -r Steven *
```

[steven.mlodzianoski.com/post/10784353754/control-r](http://steven.mlodzianoski.com/post/10784353754/control-r)

Answer (score 2):

Enabling the `completion_strip_exe` option (specific to the Cygwin port of Bash) does what you want:

```
shopt -s completion_strip_exe
```

For more details, see [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1119557/247588) to a similar question.