# Tab completion for command arguments fail in Cygwin due to `.exe` extension

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin, tab-completion, readline

Is there a configuration option in Cygwin so that when Bash completes the name of the command, the filename’s `.exe` suffix is ignored (not included)?

---

#### Explanation of the problem

When using tab completion in Bash on a Cygwin system to complete the name of a command, the `.exe` extension is appended to the command name, e.g, typing `opens` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> completes the command to `openssl.exe`.

The command runs fine (with MS Windows the `.exe` extension is optional when running a command) but the problem is that the `_openssl()` completion function provided by the [`bash-completion`](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) package is only configured to provide completions of arguments for `openssl` – not `openssl.exe`. For example:

```
$ complete -p openssl openssl.exe
complete -o default -F _openssl openssl
bash: complete: openssl.exe: no completion specification
```

The same issue exists when trying to complete arguments for *all* executable commands.

I currently use Bash with Emacs mode configured for Readline editing so I can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by two <kbd>Backspace</kbd> presses to remove the `.exe` suffix before I start to type the arguments for the command. Ideally, I’d like to avoid having to do this every time I run a command.

---

#### What I’ve tried/researched

I figured that is probably not possible without modifying the source code of the Cygwin DLL or of Bash’s command completion (`pcomplete.c`). However, I notice that the Bash builtins, `type` and `command` automatically strip the `.exe` suffix from the names of executable files, e.g.,

```
$ type -a openssl
openssl is /usr/bin/openssl

$ command -v openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

It seems that Bash running in Cygwin has some mechanism for providing the bare command name (without the `.exe` extension). However, I’ve been at a loss as to how – or if – this can be used to omit the file extension when completing commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that there **is** a configuration option in Cygwin that configures Bash to not include a filename’s `.exe` extension when it completes the name of a command.

Enabling the `completion_strip_exe` option (specific to the Cygwin port of Bash) does what I want:

```
shopt -s completion_strip_exe
```

---

This feature is not very obviously documented: it gets a cursory mention in the *Pathname Expansion* section of the Cygwin man page for Bash (it is not included in the upstream source code so is not documented in the official man page or [documentation for Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html)). I came across it while perusing `/usr/share/doc/Cygwin/bash.README` (some 4 months after asking this question):

> 7b. using 'shopt -s completion_strip_exe' makes completion strip .exe suffixes.

It seems that this option has been available in Cygwin Bash for over 5 years:

> ----- version 4.1.9-1 -- 2010-12-29 -----
>   Add EXECIGNORE and completion_strip_exe patches from Dan Colascione.

Further research shows that the patch for this feature was [submitted by Dan Colascione](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-11/msg00026.html) back in November 2010 with the [following description](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-11/msg00022.html):

> `completion_strip_exe` is a new shell option. When enabled, bash tries to use the short name of a program instead of its longer ".-exe"-suffixed one. With this on, pin completes to "ping".

Many thanks to Dan Colascione (I've just sent him a personal email to thank him personally) for this feature and the Bash maintainers for providing such a great shell.